# Identifying your own message RSA

Tags: cryptography, rsa, aes, sha256

I have a Software that Encrypts message using AES , the random generated AES key is Encrypted by the receiver's public RSA key. now when I send the message to multiple users...

Sender Side :

1. Message is Encrypted by Random hashed (sha256) AES KEY
2. The AES key is then Encrypted many time and appended to the encrypted message using each receiver's public key.
3. the message has [ number for receivers, [list of encrypted keys], Encrypted message]

Receiver Side:

1. get the number of receivers
2. loop thru the appended encrypted keys and decrypt using your Private RSA. until you find the one intended for you. such that when he/she decrypt the key they get the AES Key.

3.decrypt the message using AES key.

Knowing that the key is of base 64 string which means it ends with '=', and of the length 256 because of the sha

the Question IS :
How Do i know (if I'm the receiver) that the Decrypted key using my Private RSA is correct Automatically ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: You will have to edit the question and make it clearer if you want to get a useful response. The question as it stands correctly is not clear. When you send the message to a recipient, how does the recipient come to know about your AES key? How do you decrypt the key with your private RSA key when it was never encrypted with your public RSA key?

Comment: Thank you for the note, I have edited the Q hopefully its clear now

Comment: `The AES key is then Encrypted many time and appended to the encrypted message using each receiver's public key.` - How should we interpret this? If there are three recipients with their public keys as P_1, P_2 and P_3, do you append ENC(ENC(ENC(aes_key, P_1), P_2), P_3) or do you append ENC(aes_key, P_1), ENC(aes_key, P_2) and ENC(aes_key, P_3)?

Comment: `ENC(aes_key, P_1), ENC(aes_key, P_2) and ENC(aes_key, P_3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions: Is the protocol you describe fixed, or might it be modified in any way? If it is fixed, which padding scheme do you use for RSA? PKCS#1 v1.5, OAEP or none at all?

1. If the protocol might be modified, you could use a cipher mode with authentication, such as EAX, CCM or GCM. If RSA key transport decryption fails silently, so will the authenticated AES decryption.
2. Use a variation of RSA-OAEP for the key transport that provides "plain text awareness" as described here: http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2346.

Comment: Also, the RSA encrypted key structure should included something like a key id (e.g. 64 bit of a hash of the public key) so that identifying which RSA encrypted key was meant for you is easy.

Comment: I can use either `PKCS#1 v1.5`or `OAEP` what are you suggesting here ?\\

what you are saying sounds interesting, but my application works on a local machine, we still don't want to make it work via any type of network. as I read and if I fully understood; CCM cannot be used in this case.[for the time being]

Comment: Regular RSA-OAEP might be fine if you just use the return value from decryption for finding the encrypted key intended for you. It might however help if you could describe more closely your exact security requirements and threat scenario. Do you require confidentiality only, or authentication and integrity as well?

Comment: BTW, GregS is absolutely right that the RSA encrypted keys should be paired with a key id, to make it easier for the recipient to find the correct encrypted key. There might be a few other things you should do as well, but it depends on your exact security requirements. For instance, are you sure the sending mechanism you use is such that you do need confidentiality (AES encryption) but not authentication or non-repudiation (such as a digital signature that proves the message came from a specific sender)?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to find this encrypted message belongs to which receiver.

But you can do is try to decrypt the message if the decrypt is successful then that is the Receiver